# Iterate through Contours - OpenCV ( C# )

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am trying to get Area of a contour using `ContourArea()` method in OpenCV (C#). It always returns the same value for the Area in each iteration.
Here is the relevant part of my Code.

```
public void getcontour()
    {
        IplImage binary_image= Cv.LoadImage("binary.png", LoadMode.GrayScale);
        CvMemStorage memory = new CvMemStorage();
        OpenCvSharp.CvSeq<CvPoint> contours;

        Cv.FindContours(binary_image, memory, out contours);
        double area=0;

        for (int k=0; k<=contours.Total;k++)
        {
            area= contours.ContourArea();
            /*need to access properties such as width & height of current contour in here*/
        }

        //draw contours
        IplImage save = Cv.CreateImage(binary_image.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1);
        Cv.DrawContours(save, contours, col1, col2, 1, 1);
        Cv.SaveImage("cont.png", save);

    }
```

Comment: in c++ , it would be contourArea(contours[i]) . in other words, i do not see, how you iterate the list of contours there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to iterate through `contours` with `OpenCv (C#)`
Here is the code.

```
public void getcontour()
{
    IplImage binary_image= Cv.LoadImage("binary.png", LoadMode.GrayScale);
    CvMemStorage memory = new CvMemStorage();
    OpenCvSharp.CvSeq<CvPoint> contours;

    Cv.FindContours(binary_image, memory, out contours);
    double area=0;

    while (contours != null) 
    {
        area = contours.ContourArea();
        /* logic */
        contours = contours.HNext;

    }
 }
```